# How can the SelectDirectory Dialog in Delphi dynamically validate the highlighted folder?

Tags: delphi, dialog, directory

Is there a way to enable / disable the Ok button in the SelectDirectory Dialog based on a validation rule, for example:

- enable the OK button if the name of the highlighted folder is 'config'
- enable the OK button if the highlighted folder contains a file with the name '.project' and a folder with the name '.settings'

?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it if you use the [`ShBrowseForFolder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762115.aspx) API function. I think Delphi comes with a `SelectDirectory` version that wraps that function, although the wrapper might not provide enough access for what you'd need to do with it. You need to include a [callback function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762598.aspx) for the [`lpfn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773205.aspx) parameter with this signature:

```
function BrowseCallbackProc(Wnd: HWnd; uMsg: UInt; lParam, lpData: LParam): Integer; stdcall;
```

When the selection changes, the dialog box will call the function you provided with `bffm_SelChanged` as the `uMsg` parameter. The third parameter will be a PIDL representing the current selection, so you may need to call [`ShGetPathFromIDList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762194.aspx) to determine the string name. You can control the OK button by sending messages back to the dialog box's window handle in the `Wnd` parameter. For example:

```
SendMessage(Wnd, bffm_EnableOK, 0, 0); // disable the button
SendMessage(Wnd, bffm_EnableOK, 0, 1); // enable the button
```

Don't forget to re-enable the button for *good* selections after you've disabled it for invalid selections.

If the criterion for a valid selection is that the directory should contain a file with a certain name, be sure to include the `bif_BrowseIncludeFiles` flag so people can see what files are there.

Comment: Very nice.  I wish the directory selection controls in the VCL and JVCL provided an event handler for this.

Answer (score 5):

Just for complement the excellent answer of @Rob.

See this code.

```
uses  ShlObj;

function BrowseCallbackProc(hwnd: HWND; MessageID: UINT; lParam: LPARAM; lpData: LPARAM): Integer; stdcall;
var
    DirName:  array[0..MAX_PATH] of Char;
    pIDL   :  pItemIDList;
begin
  case  MessageID    of
    BFFM_INITIALIZED:SendMessage(hwnd, BFFM_SETSELECTION, 1, lpData);
    BFFM_SELCHANGED :begin
                        pIDL := Pointer(lParam);
                        if  Assigned(PIDL) then
                        begin
                          SHGetPathFromIDList(pIDL, DirName);
                          if DirectoryExists(DirName) then
                           if (ExtractFileName(DirName)='config') then    //you can add more validations here
                            SendMessage(hwnd, BFFM_ENABLEOK, 0, 1) //enable the ok button
                           else
                            SendMessage(hwnd, BFFM_ENABLEOK, 0, 0) //disable the ok button
                          else
                          SendMessage(hwnd, BFFM_ENABLEOK, 0, 0);
                        end
                        else
                          SendMessage(hwnd, BFFM_ENABLEOK, 0, 0);
                     end;
  end;

  Result := 0;
end;

function SelectFolderDialogExt(Handle: Integer; var SelectedFolder: string): Boolean;
var
  ItemIDList: PItemIDList;
  JtemIDList: PItemIDList;
  DialogInfo: TBrowseInfo;
  Path: PAnsiChar;
begin
  Result := False;
  Path   := StrAlloc(MAX_PATH);
  SHGetSpecialFolderLocation(Handle, CSIDL_DRIVES, JtemIDList);
  with DialogInfo do
  begin
    pidlRoot      := JtemIDList;
    //ulFlags       := BIF_RETURNONLYFSDIRS;     //only select directories
    hwndOwner     := GetActiveWindow;
    SHGetSpecialFolderLocation(hwndOwner, CSIDL_DRIVES, JtemIDList);
    pszDisplayName := StrAlloc(MAX_PATH);
    lpszTitle       := PChar('Select a folder');
    lpfn            := @BrowseCallbackProc;
    lParam            := LongInt(PChar(SelectedFolder));
  end;

  ItemIDList := SHBrowseForFolder(DialogInfo);

  if (ItemIDList <> nil) then
    if SHGetPathFromIDList(ItemIDList, Path) then
    begin
      SelectedFolder := Path;
      Result         := True;
    end;
end;
```

to execute

```
if SelectFolderDialogExt(Handle, SelectedDir) then
  ShowMessage(SelectedDir);
```